# Embedding tracking codes in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, marketo

I'm looking for the best way to implement tracking codes into my Angular 2 app. Not Google Analytics, but 3rd party suppliers like Marketo and others.  I need the codes to fire each time I load a component(page).  I've tried using the router changes with only partial success (and some unexpected results). Some version of this kind of worked but not fully.

```
this.router.events.subscribe(() => {
     //tracking code goes here
});
```

Has anyone else had success with 3rd party tracking on Angular2 or other SPAs?  Putting the  tags in the template files doesn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a guard on any route you want to track. It will be called every time the route is activated:

```
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

export class TrackingGuard implements CanActivate
{

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean
    {
        console.log(state.url);
        console.log(state.queryParams);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And in your route definitions where you specify which component for the route just add `canActivate: [TrackingGuard]` under it. In the above example you will have access to the url and any query params. Would recommend making some other service which makes the request to the tracking api and just call if from the guard.